# FAST LOAD - FDL4818 FastLoad Terminated Error

Tags: teradata

I have created Below fast load scripts which is loading data from flat file to teradata table.

```
   fastload << EOF >>  ${BASE_DIR}/Test_Load_Fastload_log

   SESSIONS 4;
   .logon ${TDPID}/${TD_LOGON}
    SET RECORD VARTEXT "    ";

    Define
    WSID (VARCHAR(10)),
    Server_Name (VARCHAR(30)),
    Technology (VARCHAR(50)),
    Env (VARCHAR(10))

    File=$BASE_DIR/workstation_source.dat;


     BEGIN LOADING WORK_DB.WS_test
     ERRORFILES WORK_DB.WS_test_Err1,WORK_DB.WS_test_Err2
    ;

       INSERT INTO WORK_DB.WS_test VALUES
    (:WSID,
     :Server_Name,
     :Technology,
     :Env );
      END LOADING;
```

This is loading data successfully in table but giving return code as 0.
But after that fast load is being teminated with FDL4818 FastLoad Terminated Error.

Below is the log.

06:37:08 Logging off all sessions
* *06:37:09 Total processor time used = '0.1 Seconds'
     .        Start : Thu Jun  6 06:37:04 2013
     .        End   : Thu Jun  6 06:37:09 2013
     .        Highest return code encountered = '0'.
**** 06:37:09 FDL4818 FastLoad Terminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including a .QUIT; or a .LOGOFF; command at the end of your script.

**EDIT**
The `FDL4818 FastLoad Terminated` message is a normal part of the completion message for a FastLoad job that has completed outside the Loading Phase. FastLoad jobs completing within the Loading Phase will display `FDL4818 FastLoad Paused` instead.

This completion message will not affect the return code that is returned to the operating system or parent process.

Comment: Used both .QUIT or .LOGOFF but getting same result.

Comment: @navku As Rob said, that message is normal; it is NOT an error.  Was your table `WORK_DB.WS_test` populated correctly?  If not, do you see anything in the error tables?

Answer (score 0):

This a message not an error.

You should check the following part of the message to check if there was an error or not:

*** Highest return code encountered = ***

If the value is 0, as in your case, the job is completed successfully without any ERROR.

If value is other than 0, e.g 8 or 12, there is some error.